# Creating a trapezium in CSS and/or HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've found plenty of tutorials for creating Trapezoids using CSS3 but I am looking to create a four sided shape where none of the side are parallel (trapezium) like the one in the picture below.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920754/how-to-draw-a-trapezium-trapezoid-with-css3

Comment: No... the top and bottom edges of that are parallel.

Comment: Does it have to be a "factory" which generates those shapes? If not, look at my answer. This will create just one example.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without using the canvas element?

Comment: Yes, It is possible without canvas

Comment: @Ani - That's good to know! Want to share?

Comment: Caught up in something right now...but will do share...I have done this before

Comment: I guess people are going sane for shapes, please read my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069723/how-to-transform-each-side-of-a-shape-separately-using-css#comment29895918_20069723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this "by hand"
html:

```
<canvas id="polygon" />
```

javascript

```
var polygon = document.getElementById('polygon').getContext('2d');
polygon.fillStyle = '#f00';
polygon.beginPath();
polygon.moveTo(0, 0);
polygon.lineTo(90,50);
polygon.lineTo(70, 70);
polygon.lineTo(0, 90);
polygon.closePath();
polygon.fill();
```

this doesn't make shure it's convex and it has no parallel lines. You have to put in the correct coordinates.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8t4rZ/

Comment: That's awesome... is there also any way of creating a border radius on the angles?

Comment: ok, this is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255512/how-to-draw-a-rounded-rectangle-on-html-canvas

Answer (score 2):

Okay..Sorry for being late. Here's my answer:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fELER/1/

CSS:

```
#up-triangle {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-bottom: 200px solid yellow; 
   border-left: 100px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 100px solid transparent; 
}

#right-triangle {
   position:absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left:175px;
   width: 50px; 
   height: 100px; 
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 100px 0 0 300px; 
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
   -webkit-transform: skew(29deg); 
   -moz-transform: skew(29deg); 
   -o-transform: skew(29deg);
   transform: skew(29deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="up-triangle"></div>
<div id="right-triangle"></div>
```

Some useful links:
http://www.css3shapes.com/

http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 0):

```
#box {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

CSS trapezoid

Comment: I'm looking for a trapezium (no parallel sides). Thanks